# Setting the orderLine property on an item when updating an invoice

Tags: c#, web-services, netsuite

My problem is that after creating an invoice, I can never get new line items to reference their corresponding sales order line item.

I have been generating invoices via SuiteTalk.  When I initially create an invoice, I empty the lineItemList and add back in the items I need.  I make sure the orderLine property matches the sales order line item line number.  This works great.

But when I try and update the invoice with additional line items, I can never get the new items to retain their orderLine property.  The orderLine property is used for the "Invoiced" column on the Sales Order.

In order to get the referencing to be correct, I need to delete the invoice and create it again with all of the line items I need.

Does anyone know if what I am trying to do is possible?

---

In this example, I use this CreateInvoice function to create the invoice from scratch and add it to NetSuite.  Everything works as expected.

```
public void CreateInvoice(SalesOrder salesOrder) {
    Invoice brandNewInvoice = new Invoice() {
        createdFrom = new RecordRef() {
            internalId = salesOrder.internalId,
        },
        entity = salesOrder.entity,
        tranDate = endDate,
        tranDateSpecified = true,
        startDate = startDate,
        startDateSpecified = true,
        endDate = endDate,
        endDateSpecified = true,
        itemList = new InvoiceItemList(),
    };


    invoice.itemList.item = GetInvoiceItemList(salesOrder); //see the function shown further down

    netSuiteService.add(brandNewInvoice);
}
```

In this example, the invoice is already created and so I get it from NetSuite and then replace the existing itemList with a new one.  After the update, the invoice will now have NO orderLine property for any of the line items.  The invoice also loses its "Created From" field because there are no line items with the orderLine property set.

```
public void UpdateInvoice(SalesOrder salesOrder, String invoiceInternalId) {
    Invoice invoice = GetNetSuiteInvoice(invoiceInternalId);        

    invoice.itemList.item = GetInvoiceItemList(salesOrder); //see the function shown further down


    netSuiteService.update(invoice);
}
```

this is the function used to create the itemList:

```
public InvoiceItem[] GetInvoiceItemList(SalesOrder salesOrder) {
    InvoiceItem[] invoiceItemList = new InvoiceItem[salesOrder.itemList.item.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < salesOrder.itemList.item.Length; i++) {
        SalesOrderItem soItem = salesOrder.itemList.item[i];
        double quantity = 1;

        invoiceItemList[i] = new InvoiceItem() {
            item = new RecordRef() {
                internalId = soItem.item.internalId,
                name = soItem.item.name,
            },
            amount = quantity * Double.Parse(soItem.rate),
            amountSpecified = true,
            quantity = quantity,
            quantitySpecified = true,
            price = new RecordRef() {
                internalId = soItem.price.internalId,
                name = soItem.price.name,
            },
            rate = soItem.rate,
            orderLine = soItem.line, //this will establish the link between the invoice and the sales order
            orderLineSpecified = true,
            taxRate1 = soItem.taxRate1,
            taxRate1Specified = true,
        };
    }

    return invoiceItemList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, when transforming a transaction to another transaction (e.g. SO to Inv, PO to IR). When you transform, most of the information from the source transaction will be carried over. Like what you are doing which is creating an Invoice from Sales Order(Base on your code below).

```
        createdFrom = new RecordRef() {
        internalId = salesOrder.internalId,
    },
```

You don't need to get the line item information from the Sales Order and put it in the Invoice because it will be pre-populated once you create it form Sales Oder(unless you need to change a value of a line item column).

One behavior of a transformed record(Invoice in your case), if you remove a line item from the Invoice you will lose the link to the Sales order(orderLine) and if you remove all the line item you will totally lose the link between the two transactions (createdfrom). This is what you are experiencing. orderLine/createdFrom is a field populated by the system, it looks like you are populating it but you are not.

Comment: orderLine is definitely something I can modify on the initial add operation, but it seems I can't modify it on an update operation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you are looking for is the intialize operation. You need to use initialize in order for Netsuite to properly fill in the created from and orderline props. From the NS Help there is a C# example of creating a Cash Sale:

private void Initialize()
        {
            this.login(true);

```
        InitializeRef ref1 = new InitializeRef();
        ref1.type = InitializeRefType.salesOrder;

                //internal id of the sales order to be converted to cash sale
        ref1.internalId = "792"; 
        ref1.typeSpecified = true;

        InitializeRecord rec = new InitializeRecord();
        rec.type = InitializeType.cashSale;
        rec.reference = ref1;

        ReadResponse read1 = _service.initialize(rec);
            }
```

Comment: In my examples, I was trying to show that I can create an invoice from scratch successfully, but the update is unsuccessful, even though I basically use the same code to build them.

Comment: In my situation, the invoice has already been created and I want to update it with some additional items.  Example: Sales Order has ItemA, ItemB and ItemC.  The invoice is created with only ItemA.  At this point, everything looks correct; the SO shows it has invoiced itemA.  Now, I update the invoice and add ItemB, but this doesn't work.  It seems the update operation discards the orderLine; I was hoping there was a way to prevent this.

Comment: You cannot do this. If you want to consolidate invoices you generally need to do that as a custom record/custom form depending on your requirements.

Comment: Correct, I would use initialize to create the invoice.

Comment: Thanks.  (I was hoping that wasn't the answer... and now back to the drawing board)

Comment: Again, if you updated an transformed transaction by removing a line item or the entire line item and adding it again it would discard the relationship.